# Error installing Android Studio in Ubuntu

Tags: android-studio, ubuntu-16.04

I am trying to install Android Studio.

I download the Android IDE and SDK from Google and installed the Java JDK.

Unfortunately, when I open Android Studio I am faced with this error:

[image: Gradle Sync Failed]

Comment: You should copy & paste the message in your question, instead of a screenshot.

Comment: 2:56:06 PM System Health
           OpenJDK shows intermittent performance and UI issues. We recommend using the Oracle JRE/JDK.
           Do not show again.
2:56:20 PM StackOverflowError: null

Comment: "System Health OpenJDK" ?